# Is it safe to store files root of host

Tags: host

When I upload files to my site they go to `/home/myusername/public_html/uploads` but I can save them to `/home/myusername/uploads`.

My question: Is it good to upload them to outside of public_html. Can my files in host be exposed of hazard ?

Comment: well, it depends. What are you uploading? National secrets? Or images for your famous blog post? And who may or may not see it? But in general; placing them outside the http root is more secure, but also there it is possibly insecure. If you want to have 100% security, don't upload them.

Comment: There many type of files which I've upload like PDF, pictures, zip, exe and user can download them via link.